# Objective-C: Potential leak of an object stored into NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am a newbie to Objective-C. XCode highlights the following code as an issue.
`_myCookies` is a private variable of my class where I store the received cookies.

```
@implementation MessageSender {
  NSArray *_myCookies;
}
...
// Socket open callback
- (void) gotData:(MySocket *) socket {
  NSDictionary *responseHeaders = (__bridge NSDictionary*)CFHTTPMessageCopyAllHeaderFields(socket.HTTPHeaders);
  _myCookies = [NSHTTPCookie cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields:responseHeaders
                                                         forURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];

}
```

[image]

The highlighted issues are:

1. Call to function 'CFHTTPMessageCopyAllHeaderFields' returns a Core Foundation object with a +1 retain count
2. Object leaked: object allocated and stored into 'responseHeaders' is not referenced later in this execution path and has a retain count of +1

How do I resolve this one?
I am using ARC. I want to store the cookies in my class so I can later use them while sending the request, but I want to let the socket take care of its responseHeaders.

Comment: can you post more code than this?

Comment: I am using ARC for this

Comment: Maybe you forgot to copy something from wherever you got that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to transfer ownership of the CoreFoundation object to ARC:

```
NSDictionary *responseHeaders = CFBridgingRelease(CFHTTPMessageCopyAllHeaderFields(socket.HTTPHeaders));
```

CF objects are not managed by ARC, and must be released manually. When you use a `__bridge` cast, you're simply casting the object directly with no change in ownership. This is what causes your memory leak (you need to manually release CF objects with `CFRelease` when you're done with them).

You can avoid all this manual memory management trouble by simply using `CFBridgingRelease` to cast the object (as in the code example above). This transfers ownership of the CF object to ARC, so ARC will automatically handle releasing that object for you, and everything will work just fine with no extra work on your part.

Comment: The MySocket class seems to be releasing the HTTPHeaders when it cleans up the socket using `CFRelease(HTTPHeaders)`. So the `CFBridgingRelease` will not interfere with the release of the headers when that happens?

Comment: No, because you're not transferring ownership of the headers themselves, you're transferring ownership of the object returned by `CFHTTPMessageCopyAllHeaderFields`, which returns a copy of the header fields (as indicated by the name), which is a completely different object. Try using the code I suggested, and build and analyse. If this causes an issue, the static analyser will tell you about it.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `__bridge`, use `__bridge_transfer` which transfers ownership of the object to ARC.  Ex:

```
NSDictionary *responseHeaders = (__bridge_transfer NSDictionary*)CFHTTPMessageCopyAllHeaderFields(socket.HTTPHeaders);
```

Comment: I thought `CFBridgingRelease` was the new, preferred way to do this (not that it should really make a difference).

Comment: Ahh looks like Apple has recommended that over `__bridge_transfer` for clarity.  They do the same thing under the hood though, since CFBridgingRelease just calls `(__bridge_transfer id)`.